# Is it a good idea to refer to the top-most table from a descendant table in a hierarchy of foreign-key related tables?

Tags: database-design, foreign-keys, relational-database

I'm in the process of designing a database that contains, among other things, information about customers. I have 3 tables: `customers`, `addresses` and `contacts`. Table `addresses` has a foreign key to `customers` (a customer can have many addresses). Every address, can have many contacts, so I have a foreign key from `contacts` to `addresses` as well.

The current schema looks like this:

```
[customers]<-----[addresses]<-----[contacts]
```

If I wanted to retrieve the contacts from a customer, I would use a subquery/join that first grabbed the addresses the given customer has. But here is where my question arises: would it be a good idea to add a foreign key to `contacts` that references to `customers`? This would make queries simpler, but I'm not sure if adding this redundancy could imply undesirable effects. For example, if somebody manually changed the foreign key of an address to another customer and forgot to change the same key from contacts, then the data would be broken.

I would like to know if there's some sort of "good practice" when creating foreign keys in tables that are indirectly related through other tables.

Thank you!

Comment: Why a subquery when JOIN's are invented to solve this issue?

Comment: @FrankHeikens I implied "joins" in the category of "subqueries". Edited.

Comment: When a contact is related to an address, you only make that relation (foreign key). Just stay to 3NF for you model and work it out. If somebody has the power to update the value of a relation (the foreign key) that person is also responsible for any mistakes made.  And people do make mistakes, don't worry about that!

Comment: Are you using MySQL or Postgresql?

Comment: Can't two customers share the same address?

Comment: @jarlh PostgreSQL. And no, in my case two customers cannot share the same address.

Comment: Then you can remove the (unrelated) MySQL tag,

Comment: @jarlh I'm not sure that you need any product tags for this question as it is very general and can be applied to any relational database product.

Comment: @Shadow, I agree. But completely unrelated tags should always be avoided.

Comment: Please listen to Frank Heikens:  Do not add the extra foreign key to `customers`.
If you want to simplify queries, for example so that end users can use the data for reporting, then create `view` objects for that.  Should your analytics and reporting needs grow, then consider creating a reporting database to be fed from your transactional system.